# Docker compose available in python without internet access

Tags: python, centos, pip, docker-compose, ansible

I'm having the issue needing to use docker compose in python (for using the docker_service functionality in Ansible), but its not possible to install using pip because of a network policy of the company (the VM has no network access only acces to a RPM). I although can use a yum repository that contains docker compose.

What I tried is to install "docker compose" (version 1.18.0) using yum. Although python is not recognizing docker compose and suggest me to use pip: "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`

Since in most cases I can solve this issue by installing this using yum install python-, I already looked the web for a package called python-docker-compose but no result :(

minimalistic ansible script for test:

```
- name: Run using a project directory
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - docker_service:
        project_src: flask
        state: absent
```

hope anyone can help.

**SOLUTION:**

After some digging around I solved the issue by doing a local download on a machine that has internet:

> pip download -d /tmp/docker-compose-local docker-compose

archiving all the packages that were downloaded in the folder

> cd tmp 
>   tar -czvf docker-compose-python.tgz ./docker-compose-local

since the total size of the package is slightly bigger than 1MB I added the file to the ansible docker role.

In the docker role a local install is done:

> cd /tmp 
>   tar -xzvf docker-compose-python.tgz pip install --no-index
>   --find-links file:/tmp/docker-compose-local/ docker_compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I solved the issue by doing a local download on a machine that has internet:

> pip download -d /tmp/docker-compose-local docker-compose

archiving all the packages that were downloaded in the folder

> cd tmp
>
> tar -czvf docker-compose-python.tgz ./docker-compose-local

since the total size of the package is slightly bigger than 1MB I added the file to the ansible docker role.

In the docker role a local install is done:

> cd /tmp
>
> tar -xzvf docker-compose-python.tgz
>
> pip install --no-index --find-links file:/tmp/docker-compose-local/
>   docker_compose

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual environment!

unless you can not do that either, it depends whether the company policy is NOT to write on everyone's python (then you are fine) or whether you can not use pip (even in your own environment).
If you CAN do that then:

```
virtualenv docker_compose -p python3
source docker_compose/bin/activate
pip install docker-compose
```

You get all this junk:

```
Collecting docker-compose
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/03Collecting docker-pycreds>=0.3.0 (from docker<4.0,>=3.4.1->docker-compose)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/bf/7e70aeebc40407fbdb96fa9f79fc8e4722ea889a99378303e3bcc73f4ab5/docker_pycreds-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: PyYAML, docopt, texttable, dockerpty
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyYAML ... done
Stored in directory: /home/eserrasanz/.cache/pip/wheels/ad/da/0c/74eb680767247273e2cf2723482cb9c924fe70af57c334513f
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for docopt ... done
Stored in directory: /home/eserrasanz/.cache/pip/wheels/9b/04/dd/7daf4150b6d9b12949298737de9431a324d4b797ffd63f526e
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for texttable ... done
Stored in directory: /home/eserrasanz/.cache/pip/wheels/99/1e/2b/8452d3a48dad98632787556a0f2f90d56703b39cdf7d142dd1
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dockerpty ... done
Stored in directory: /home/eserrasanz/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/1e/86/bd0a97a0907c6c654af654d5875d1d4383dd1f575f77cee4aa
Successfully installed PyYAML-3.13 cached-property-1.5.1 certifi-2018.8.24 chardet-3.0.4 docker-3.5.0 docker-compose-1.22.0 docker-pycreds-0.3.0 dockerpty-0.4.1 docopt-0.6.2 idna-2.6 jsonschema-2.6.0 requests-2.18.4 six-1.11.0 texttable-0.9.1 urllib3-1.22 websocket-client-0.53.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your responds. I think this is a neat solution for your scenario, but apparently my issue wasn't in being able to install on the machine using pip but rather that pip couldn't download packages from the internet because of a network policy.

Comment: then you have to go with some installation from source I supose :(

Comment: found a solution using pip local download. I updated the issue. Thank you for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to install using curl from GitHub, assuming this is not blocked by your network policy. Link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
# Outputs: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build 1719ceb
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your responds. Docker compose does get installed when network access is granted, but sadly python still throws the message: Unable to load docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

To complete answer from E.Serra you can use ansible to create the virtualenv, use pip and install docker-compose in one task this way.

```
- pip:
    name: docker-compose
    virtualenv: /my_app/venv
```